# Why is "Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: Hardware Security Test Interface failed" being shown in msinfo32.exe?

Tags: windows-10, security, encryption

The full message is:

> Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected

It is shown under the Device encryption support field in msinfo32.exe.

What does this mean? How can I enable "automatic device encryption"?

Security features in my PC:

1. Secure Boot: Enabled
2. Core Isolation: Enabled
3. Memory Integrity: Enabled
4. BitLocker: Disabled
5. TPM is present in my PC

Comment: First step, run:
powercfg /a
and check if
Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
is supported. If not, then Modern Standby is not supported.

Comment: @Brian2000 is S(0 Lowe Power Idle) even supported on desktop computers? I thoughjt this was a laptop only thing.  It seems like MS is following typical form with a half baked solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer is based on the assumption that your version is Windows Home.
I have highlighted below some important parts of the message:

> Reasons for failed **automatic** device encryption: **Hardware Security Test Interface failed** and the device is not **Modern Standby, TPM is not usable**.

This message arrives when device encryption is unavailable in Control Panel.
It is only shown in `msinfo32.exe` as the reason for this missing option.

The situation is that the TPM is usable and would work with Bitlocker,
but not with device encryption.

The important part here is the word "automatic".
Microsoft is saying that it would have enabled device encryption automatically
if all the requirements were fulfilled and the login was with a Microsoft account.
In this case, the all-important recovery key would be saved to your
OneDrive cloud storage for future recovery.

A Windows Pro user would not be required to back up his key to the cloud,
nor to have a device with certain capabilities, as Bitlocker will work
without it.
He could even choose to use a password instead of the TPM (which Microsoft
frowns upon as an unsafe practice).

Microsoft is here protecting Windows Home users, supposedly acting in their
best interest by not enabling disk encryption automatically.
Home users are assumed to not know enough about disk encryption,
so this keeps them from unknowingly using encryption and possibly locking
themselves out of their computer in the future,
even rendering their data inaccessible.

In short, this is a warning that you can ignore if you don't intend to encrypt
your disk.

For more information see the articles:

- [Difference Between Device Encryption and BitLocker Device Encryption on Windows 10](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/the-two-types-of-device-encryptions-in-windows-10/)
- [How to use Bitlocker on Windows 10 Home](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33596/How-to-use-Bitlocker-on-Windows-10-Home.html)

Comment: I have encrypted one flash drive with bitlocker and few days later I can't access it and have this message in msinfo too! So WTF? I didn't change any configuration anywhere. It's Gigabyte Aorus Elite v2. How can it be so flakey?

Comment: I'm using Windows pro and I have that message. Though, I guess I don't know the difference between "device encryption" and "hard drive encryption". I'm going to have to research this further.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing that particular message is likely because you've not enabled the TPM module within your UEFI/bios settings.
Your system evidently meets the hardware requirements for Win11, however the state of the required feature sets have not been fully activated. Similarly, Win11 will successfully install when Secure boot is enabled, yet not active.

-- https://www.thewindowsclub.com/pcr7-binding-is-not-supported-in-windows